# ClassificationMeasurements without the Classifier

Tags: probability-or-statistics, machine-learning

I only have classifications (a list of inputs and outputs), but not a `ClassifierFunction`, how can I still use `ClassificationMeasurements` to compute statistics on my data?

With `PrintDefinitions[]` I was thinking we could do something like this to create the ClassifierMeasurementsObject

```
predictions = {"A", "A", "B", "A"}
truth = {2.2 -> "A", 2.7 -> "A", 4.5 -> "B", 1.4 -> "B"};
cm = Quiet@MachineLearning`file115ClassifierPredictor`PackagePrivate`routerC[predictions, truth, {}]
```

But this didn't quite fit the bill.

Comment: Perhaps use ExternalEvaluate and scikitlearn’s metrics module?

Comment: Related (very similar) MSE question ["Visualization of experimental results: making a plot of the success rate vs. a parameter"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169537/34008).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package [ROCFunctions.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/ROCFunctions.m).

[ROCFunctions.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/ROCFunctions.m) implements all the functions defined in the Wikipedia page ["Receiver operating characteristic" (ROC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). More details are given in the blog post ["ROC for classifier ensembles, bootstrapping, damaging, and interpolation"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/roc-for-classifier-ensembles-bootstrapping-damaging-and-interpolation/).

### Code

Data (from the question):

```
predictions = {"A", "A", "B", "A"};
truth = {2.2 -> "A", 2.7 -> "A", 4.5 -> "B", 1.4 -> "B"};
```

Get the [ROCFunctions.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/ROCFunctions.m) package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/ROCFunctions.m"]
```

See the definition of `ToROCAssociation` from that package:

```
?ToROCAssociation
```

> ToROCAssociation[ {trueLabel, falseLabel}, actualLabels, predictedLabels] converts two labels lists (actual and predicted) into an Association that can be used as an argument for the ROC functions. See ROCFunctions .

Make a ROC association:

```
ra = ToROCAssociation[{"A", "B"}, truth[[All, 2]], predictions]

(* <|"TruePositive" -> 2, "FalsePositive" -> 1, 
     "TrueNegative" -> 1, "FalseNegative" -> 0|> *)
```

Compute measures:

```
msrFuncs = {"Accuracy", "Precision", "Recall", "FalsePositiveRate", "SPC"};
AssociationThread[msrFuncs, N@Through[ROCFunctions[msrFuncs][ra]]]

(* <|"Accuracy" -> 0.75, "Precision" -> 0.666667, 
      "Recall" -> 1., "FalsePositiveRate" -> 0.5, "SPC" -> 0.5|> *)
```

### Related question and answer

See [this MSE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169551/34008) of the related (very similar) MSE question ["Visualization of experimental results: making a plot of the success rate vs. a parameter"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169537/34008).

Comment: This is helpful but I was hoping for an answer that enabled me to use the built-in symbol ClassifierMeasurements.

Comment: Couple of points. **1.** I made the package ROCFunctions.m before `ClassifierMeasurements` started providing ROC functions. **2.** I have tried to utilize `ClassifierFunction` and `ClassifierMeasurements` in ways that would make it convenient to use ensemble classifiers or custom classifiers. I did not have any success. [This monad implementation](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/05/15/a-monad-for-classification-workflows/) diminishes those needs for ensembles.